# What are invariants in programming languages and why is it important?

Tags: programming-languages, invariants

Can anyone explain what the invariants in programming languages are and why they matter?

Answer (score 6):

### What are Invariants

Invariants in any field - are values (usually numbers) that allow you to distinguish "objects" if those invariants are not the same.

For example if you have a mathematical term say

```
(x+3)²+1
```

and you want to transform that term one invariant would be to substitute a random number for `x`, my rng chose `x=0` - so the invariant would be

```
(0+3)²+1 = 9+1 = 10
```

then if I transform the term incorrectly

```
x²+6x+3 + 1 = x² + 6x +4
```

testing again with `x = 0` I see `0²+0+4 = 4` which is different from `10` therefore I know there had to be a mistake.
But if on the other hand I had transformed the term to

```
x²+3x+9 +1 = x²+3x+10
```

the invariant for `x=0` would be `10` again - so we see

### Why are they useful?

- different invariants => different objects
- same invariants => maybe same objects

### Example: `equational reasoning`

why has this become interesting in (functional) programming - one expression you will hear in this context is `equational reasoning` and this means just the procedure I did above if you can transform an algorithm/function/term into another one without loosing equality. This is often true for languages like haskell, by restriction of immutability, no side effects etc. whereas in oo this is often not true. Equational reasoning allows you to shrink the area where errors turned up quite good so debugging/bug finding is comparatively more easily done.

### Example: `property based testing`

Another field where invariants are common is property based testing: here the standard example for this `reverse :: [a] -> [a]`, i.e. the reverse function on (linked) lists, has the property of `reverse . reverse == id`, i.e. reversing twice is the same as doing nothing.
If you put this in a Quickcheck test - the test generator generates arbitrary lists and checks this property - if one of these (potentially) thousands of tests fail you know, where to improve your code.

### Example: `Compiler optimizations`

Some properties also can used to make optimizations of your code for example if for all functions `fmap f . fmap g == fmap (f . g)` and the left hand side traverses a data structure twice, where the right hand side only does one traversal, the compiler can substitute them and make your code twice as fast.

Answer (score 4):

An invariant is a property of your data that you expect to always hold. Invariants are important because they allow you to separate business logic from validation—your functions can safely assume that they’re not receiving invalid data.

For example, in a chess game, you have the invariant that only one piece at a time may occupy a given square on the board. Invariants can be enforced at compile-time, usually by using a static type system to make objects correct by construction, e.g., by representing the board as a matrix of optional pieces. They can also be enforced at runtime, e.g., by raising an exception when trying to make an invalid move.

The approach in functional programming languages is typically to make objects immutable, and prevent the construction of invalid states. In OOP languages, where objects are commonly mutable, methods are expected to prevent invalid state *transitions*.

Either way, enforcing invariants ensures that your program is always in a predictable state, which makes it easier to reason about your code and safely make changes without introducing regressions.

Comment: another more interesting example in the chess world would be a bishop starting on a white field can never be on a black field and vice versa